# javascript : css file path problem using nunjucks

Tags: nunjucks

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JBxGG.png)

I set the path appropriately, but there is an error.
It comes out well when you proceed with normal html, not nunjucks.

Comment: post the error you are getting

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Put your stylesheet in block

```
{% block css %}
<link rel="stylesheet" href="app.css" />
{% endblock %}
```

for more information check the [documentation](https://mozilla.github.io/nunjucks/templating.html)  **block section**